# Date filter not working as part of the DAX code

Tags: date, filter, powerbi

I have the following DAX as shown below which works fine other then the Date filtering parameter in the dax, i have built the DAX by adding one step at time (parameters), but when i add the date filtering element and try to hyperlink to the published pbix file, it re sets all the filters so no filters are applied.

```
Internet Research Report Filter =
VAR oL = "DIMSalesPerson/OfficeLocation eq '"
        & SELECTEDVALUE ( 'DIMSalesPerson'[OfficeLocation] ) & "'"
VAR oC = 
    "DIMSalesPerson/City eq '" & SELECTEDVALUE ( 'DIMSalesPerson'[City] ) & "'"
VAR oS =
    "DIMShipper/ShipCompanyName eq '"
        & SELECTEDVALUE ( 'DIMShipper'[ShipCompanyName] ) & "'"
VAR oP =
    "DIMProduct/CategoryName eq '" & SELECTEDVALUE ( 'DIMProduct'[CategoryName] ) & "'"
VAR oSP =
    "DIMSalesPerson/SalesPerson eq '"
        & SELECTEDVALUE ( 'DIMSalesPerson'[SalesPerson] ) & "'"
VAR oRegion =
    "DIMSalesPerson/SalesRegion eq '"
        & SELECTEDVALUE ( 'DIMSalesPerson'[SalesRegion] ) & "'"
VAR oDatefilter =
    IF (
        ISFILTERED ( 'Calendar'[Date] ),
        "Calendar/Date le " & MAX ( 'Calendar'[Date] ) & " and Calendar/Date ge "
            & MIN ( 'Calendar'[Date] )
    )
RETURN
    [Report URL]
        & SWITCH (
            TRUE,
            ISFILTERED ( 'DIMSalesPerson'[OfficeLocation] )
                && ISFILTERED ( 'DIMSalesPerson'[City] ), "?filter=" & oL & " and " & oC & " and " & oS & " and " & oP & " and " & oSP & " and " & oRegion & " and " & oDatefilter,
            ISFILTERED ( 'DIMSalesPerson'[OfficeLocation] ), "?filter=" & oL,
            ISFILTERED ( 'DIMSalesPerson'[City] ), "?filter=" & oC,
            ISFILTERED ( 'DIMShipper'[ShipCompanyName] ), "?filter=" & oS,
            ISFILTERED ( 'DIMProduct'[CategoryName] ), "?filter=" & oP,
            ISFILTERED ( 'DIMSalesPerson'[SalesPerson] ), "?filter=" & oSP,
            ISFILTERED ( 'DIMSalesPerson'[SalesRegion] ), "?filter=" & oRegion,
            IF (
                ISFILTERED ( 'Calendar'[Date] ),
                "Calendar/Date le " & MAX ( 'Calendar'[Date] ) & " and Calendar/Date ge "
                    & MIN ( 'Calendar'[Date] )
            )
        )
```

the date filter to work based on the max and min date selection on the date filter in the pbix file.

Comment: hi RADO,not aure what your comment was. if you posted one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in order for the above to work the dates have to be in format "YYYY-MMM-DD" in power query or use the format([Calander[Dates],"YYYY-MM-DD" as a new measure that is what i found.